How can I build a Gradle project without internet access and get a list of dependencies?
I'm working in a environment where internet access is not available. I need to build my Gradle project, but there's a proxy that blocks any package that goes through. I spoke with the security department, and they asked me to provide a list of all the dependencies the project requires so they can create exceptions in the proxy.
Is there a way to generate a comprehensive list of dependencies, including their versions, without requiring internet access?
Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Not an answer to your specific question, but that's not how it typically works. If some software development is expected within an organization without direct access to the Internet, there should be a binary management tool such as Artifactory, Nexus, or any other that could be set up to act as an internal mirror for the selected dependency repositories. Then the developers set up their projects and build tools so that they access that binary management server instead of downloading the dependencies from default repositories on the Internet.

Indeed, you're right. We have already attempted using a Nexus repository. However, due to time constraints, granting access to the proxy for some artifacts is quicker than adding everything to Nexus. Since I don't have direct access, it would involve a lot of back-and-forth emails, and some projects have tight deadlines. I asked the question just in case there is a solution that I can't find.


is quicker than adding everything - you (they) shouldn't add anything, it should be able to download any dependency from a trusted source automatically as soon as someone (your build) requires it. A dependency tree for a simplest project might consist of hundreds of dependencies, I don't believe it's even feasible to set up a proxy like this

